# XGBoost ROC AUC during training does not fit to the end result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am training a BDT using XGBoost to do binary classification on 22 features. I have 18 Million Samples. (60% for training, 40% for testing)

The ROC AUC I get during training does not fit the end result I get, and I do not understand how this can be. Also, the ROC AUC shows way more overtraining than any other metric, and it appears to have a maximum on the test data.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem before, or has any idea what's wrong with my model, or how I can find out what's wrong?

The essence of my code:

```py
params = {
 "model_params": {
    "n_estimators": 2000,
    "max_depth": 4,
    "learning_rate": 0.1,
    "scale_pos_weight": 11.986832275943744,
    "objective": "binary:logistic",
    "tree_method": "hist"
  },
  "train_params": {
    "eval_metric": [
      "logloss",
      "error",
      "auc",
      "aucpr",
      "map"
    ]
  }
}

model = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params["model_params"], use_label_encoder=False)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)], 
          **params["train_params"])

train_history = model.evals_result()

...

plt.plot(iterations, train_history["validation_0"]["auc"], label="training data")
plt.plot(iterations, train_history["validation_1"]["auc"], label="test data")

...

y_pred_proba_train = model.predict_proba(X_train)
y_pred_proba_test = model.predict_proba(X_test)

fpr_test, tpr_test, _ = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba_test[:, 1])
fpr_train, tpr_train, _ = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve(y_train, y_pred_proba_train[:, 1])

auc_test = sklearn.metrics.auc(fpr_test, tpr_test)
auc_train = sklearn.metrics.auc(fpr_train, tpr_train)

...

plt.title(f"ROC curve, AUC=(test: {auc_test:.4f}, train: {auc_train:.4f})")
plt.plot(fpr_test, tpr_test, label="test data")
plt.plot(fpr_train, tpr_train, label="train data")

...
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `scikit-learn` takes the [macro average auc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) by default, and I'm not sure what `xgboost` does, but I suspect it takes the micro average.

Is your dataset imbalanced? This could explain it, especailly if your test set isn't stratified.

Comment: I just tested this. I use `roc_curve` + `auc` manually. This yields the same results as `roc_auc_score` with `macro` , `weighted` or `None`. However, `roc_auc_score` with `micro` yields a much lower score of `0.71` for both training and test data. I don't think this is it, but interesting observation! `samples` somehow takes far too long to calculate.

Comment: And to answer your question: my dataset is imbalanced with 12:1 (classes: 0, 1) And I stratified the `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`.

Comment: Are you training on a cluster? XGBoost averages the auc for each node.

Comment: Yes, I am training on a server with multiple CPUs. I don't understand what you mean, could you provide a link for further reading or explain it in an answer? This sounds like a promising explanation.

Comment: It's in the docs (cntl-f for 'auc') - the AUC is calculated independently for the samples assigned to each node, then an average is taken..

Answer (score 1):

It's [not clear in the documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html), but when a validation set is provided, XGBoost may use the model state of the iteration with the best validation metrics (in your case, `map`) for predictions when using the scikit-learn API.

You aren't doing anything wrong; it's completely normal for a GBT to overfit when allowed to train for many iterations.

Edit: This doesn't explain it; as per the updated OP, the validation `map` continued to improve over every iteration.

Comment: What do you mean with "with the best validation metric"? 

What I am concerned about is, that the final model shows only slight overfitting, but the training history shows drastic overfitting. The AUC on the test data is higher and the AUC on the training data is lower.

Comment: Your model will use the model state at the iteration that showed the best validation `map` (the last metric you provided). This was around iteration #40, where the peak in validation auc is visible in your plot, with train and validation auc matching your own test later. 

The training history shows drastic overfitting because you continued to train for an additional 1960 iterations, but as the validation metrics did not improve, your model used the state from iteration ~40, before it became overfit, for predictions.

Comment: I think that's not true. `model.best_iteration` yields `1999` and the `map` history has not peaked at iteration <100. (I added it to the post) Also, the AUC scores I get after the training are very different from the AUC scores during training, even at iteration ~40. Or am I missing something? Thanks anyway! I did not know most of this.

Comment: Also, I did not use early stopping.

Answer (score 0):

When training on a cluster, XGBoost [calculates the AUC](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html) (ctrl-f for 'auc') as a macro average over each node. Particularly given your class imbalance, I suspect this is the culprit.

Comment: That's not it, either. I just trained it on one CPU and get basically the same result. Also, I now think the server I am working on does not really count as a distributed environment.